# ionic-cli - Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I'm using the `ionic-cli` v3.9.2 to create a project like this:

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ? What starter would you like to use: tutorial [INFO] Fetching app
>   base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-
>   base/archive/master.tar.gz) × Downloading - failed! Error: unable to
>   get local issuer certificate

I am behind a corporate firewall but I've correctly configured `npm` and `git` to use the proxy already (I was able to install `cordova` and ionic through `npm` with no issues).

Any clues?

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.4.6
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue. `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In CMD

> set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0

will solve your problem.
Problem is `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` is highly unsecure so you have to unable it.